# OrientDB: is OCommandFunction usable in 3.0.0m1?

Tags: orientdb

In version 2 OCommandFuction would be used more or less like this:

```
OCommandFunction command = new OCommandFunction(function);
ODocument doc = db.command(command).execute(args);
```

or

```
OResultSet<ODocument> rs = db.command(command).execute(args);
```

In 3.0 db.command is deprecated and the 3.0 idiomatic alternatives are documented in most use cases, except, to the best of my knowledge, for the one I described.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following should work fine:

```
 db.execute("sql", "RETURN yourFunctin()", params);
```

3.0M1 is still an early beta, so if you find any problems please report them on the official issue tracker. Thanks!